# ongr-io elasticsearch bundle implementation with doctrine symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, doctrine-orm, ongr

In our symfony2 project we want to implement elasticsearch with ongr-io bundle, but our whole system is built on doctrine. Is it possible to somehow use ongr-io elasticsearch bundle without totally redoing whole database with documents instead of entities?

Entity that I want to index (fields for search would be: name, ChildCategory and ParentCategory):

```
/**
 * Course
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="course")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CoreBundle\Repository\CourseRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
    class Course
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=false)
         */
        private $name;

        /**
         * @var ParentCategory
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ParentCategory")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parentCategory_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $parentCategory;

        /**
         * @var ChildCategory
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ChildCategory", inversedBy="courses")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="childCategory_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $childCategory;

        /**
         * @var City
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="City")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $city;

        /**
         * @var Users
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\Users", inversedBy="course")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $owner;

        /**
         * @var text
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
         */
        private $description;

        /**
         * @var Picture
         *
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CoreBundle\Entity\Picture", mappedBy="course", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
         */
        private $pictures;

        /**
         * @var Ratings
         *
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CoreBundle\Entity\Ratings", mappedBy="courseid")
         */
        private $ratings;

        public $avgRating;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's very interesting.

The first thing is Entity location. The document for ElasticsearchBundle has to be in `Document` directory. It's not a big deal. All you need to do is to create an empty class and extend entity with `@Document` annotation. Next are the fields. With `name` field there is no problem at all, just add `@property` annotation and you are good. More interesting is with relations. My suggestion would be to create separate property and in the getter return value from the relation for that field. I hope you got the idea.

**Update:**

Here's an example of documents:

AppBundle/Entity/Post

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ONGR\ElasticsearchBundle\Annotation as ES;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ES\Property(type="string")
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ES\Property(name="user", type="string")
     */
    private $esUser;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
     *
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEsUser()
    {
        return $this->esUser;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $esUser
     */
    public function setEsUser($esUser)
    {
        $this->esUser = $esUser;
    }
}
```

AppBundle/Document/Post

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Document;

use ONGR\ElasticsearchBundle\Annotation as ES;
use AppBundle\Entity\Post as OldPost;

/**
 * @ES\Document()
 */
class Post extends OldPost
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I understood you right then I simply have to create an empty class in Document folder and keep doing everything on the entity that I already have, but if I do this I get an error: " "CoreBundle\Document\Course" class cannot be parsed as document because @Document annotation is missing." It works only when I extend that class as a document too, but then won't it simply look for fields in this empty document class?

Comment: I think, I misunderstood what you want to do. If you want to persist doctrine entity to the Elasticsearch that won't help. If you will have a separate class you still will need to populate with values from the entity. Why not simply to create separate document with only those fields you need?

Comment: But won't that sort of duplication impact performance and storage usage too much?

Comment: And also in that case if I understand it right, during search process first I will simply find those documents and then by the ids' I will have to find entities with doctrine, which looks like a pretty messy solution, doesn't it?

Comment: Index everything to the elasticsearch what you need and the just show it. As far as I understand you are trying to use elasticsearch in a wrong way.

Comment: Ok I think I got the idea, thank you for your advice and patience.